# RESTClient for Firefox - Sending Dict as POST parameter

Tags: django, rest-client

I am trying to post a request to test my website using RESTClient add-on for firefox.
In body, I am passing the following text:

```
["abcd":"12", "ab":"23"]
```

but in backend (django server), I am getting error while parsing:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError: 'Key \'input0\' not found in <QueryDict: {u\'{["abcd":"12", "ab":"23"]}\': [u\'\']}>'
```

I have tried sending the request using Content-type as application/json also.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `request.body` in your Django code to access the POST data.